# React.js : Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, reactjs

I'm trying to learn react.js and found a tutorial online. I was following a react/rails tutorial from http://rny.io/rails/react/2014/07/31/reactjs-and-rails.html

The all the code was working fine until I got to the last step implementing the Comment Form. After following all the instructions, I get an error in my chrome console pointing to this line of code `var commentNodes = this.props.comments.map(function (comment, index) {` saying its "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function". The form shows up and accepts input but nothing is displayed after I submit. Also, the tutorial is a bit dated, it is still using `React.renderComponent`, I changed it to `React.render` after reading the docs. Is there some more deprecated code I missed? or Can anyone help me or tell me what I did wrong?
Thanks in Advance

```
var Comment = React.createClass({
      render: function () {
        return (
          <div className="comment">
            <h2 className="commentAuthor">
              {this.props.author}
            </h2>
              {this.props.comment}
          </div>
      );
  }
});

var CommentList = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    var commentNodes = this.props.comments.map(function (comment, index) {
      return (
        <Comment author={comment.author} comment={comment.comment} key={index} />
        );
    });

    return (
      <div className="commentList">
        {commentNodes}
      </div>
      );
  }
});

var CommentBox = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {comments: []};
  },
  componentDidMount: function () {
    this.loadCommentsFromServer();
  },
  loadCommentsFromServer: function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function (comments) {
        this.setState({comments: comments});
      }.bind(this),
      error: function (xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  handleCommentSubmit: function(comment) {
    var comments = this.state.comments;
    var newComments = comments.concat([comment]);
    this.setState({comments: newComments});
    $.ajax({
      url: this.props.url,
      dataType: 'json',
      type: 'POST',
      data: {"comment": comment},
      success: function(data) {
        this.loadCommentsFromServer();
      }.bind(this),
      error: function(xhr, status, err) {
        console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
      }.bind(this)
    });
  },
  render: function () {
    return (
      <div className="commentBox">
        <h1>Comments</h1>
        <CommentList comments={this.state.comments} />
        <CommentForm onCommentSubmit={this.handleCommentSubmit}/>
      </div>
      );
  }
});

var CommentForm = React.createClass({
  handleSubmit: function() {
    var author = this.refs.author.getDOMNode().value.trim();
    var comment = this.refs.comment.getDOMNode().value.trim();
    this.props.onCommentSubmit({author: author, comment: comment});
    this.refs.author.getDOMNode().value = '';
    this.refs.comment.getDOMNode().value = '';
    return false;
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <form className="commentForm" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Your name" ref="author" />
        <input type="text" placeholder="Say something..." ref="comment" />
        <input type="submit" value="Post" />
      </form>
      );
  }
});

var ready = function () {
  React.render(
    <CommentBox url="/comments.json" />,
    document.getElementById('comments')
  );
};

$(document).ready(ready);
```

Comment: do you have a server setup that is returning a JSON data object that contains a list called comments?

Comment: @ChrisHawkes thanks for your reply. I checked my controller etc and it is ok. It turns out the app was just missing one word. `response`, see answer below. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

The likely reason is that the comments coming back is not an array. Do a `console.log(comments)` or `debugger;` before this line: `this.setState({comments: comments});` to check your ajax response and see if comments is an array of comments. If it's anything other than array, then that's your problem, you can just put some mock data in there for now until you can get that working.

Comment: thanks!, your response helped out. I was able to debug my problem better, it turns out it was being set twice, I needed to added `response` to the code... `this.setState({comments: response.comments});` a colleague of mine pointed this out to me. Thanks again!

Comment: Jonathan, I will come back and upvote your answer when I get enough reputation. Cheers!